# Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64 vs. i386 servers on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04

Are there any important (e.g. performance) differences between AMD64 and i386 AMIs on AWS - assuming both have EBS-backed storage? Can also assume micro instances in a US availability zone.

Are the different AMIs hosted on the same physical hardware stack, or does AWS load different instance images on matching physical hardware (FYI, I realize that the point of platforms like AWS is not to think about these types of details, so maybe the answer is, "There is no functional difference").

Comment: Even Amazon's oldest servers were 64-bit capable, right at launch years ago. The only thing that might have been 32-bit-only would be an Atom or something too old to be used in a new (then) project. So that's irrelevant.

Comment: There's really no reason I can think of to run an i386 EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any important (e.g. performance) differences between AMD64
>   and i386 AMIs on AWS - assuming both have EBS-backed storage?

Other than one being 32-bit and one 64-bit? That's a pretty significant difference.

> Are the different AMIs hosted on the same physical hardware stack, or
>   does AWS load different instance images on matching physical hardware

No idea, you'll need to ask Amazon.